# Understanding EmberJS and Rails backend workflow

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I'm trying to understand one thing in how EmberJS interacts with Ruby on Rails (or whatever backend you're using is probably applicable here). All of the templates we're writing are essentially done in handlebars, and EmberJS is responsible for rendering them based on what route you're on. That part I get. The thing is, when you navigate URLs, and you're using the browser's `history API`, it still hits the backend of Rails and goes through the normal hierarchy of a Rails HTTP request. That means everything from `routes.rb` to all the views being sent back up to the client are getting hit. I'm simply trying to understand if this is normal? When converting an existing Rails app to work with Ember, I'm still rendering a great deal of Rails views that are no longer applicable because of this behavior. I'm guessing they should just be deleted from the server to not waste processing time? Is this typical behavior when one uses the history API with EmberJS or other related client-side frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical if you are using the history API.  However, it is also why I would recommend turning off this feature.  The way ember typically integrates with rails is that you only have one controller action, say home#index that will ever get hit directly by navigating to a url in the browser.  Every other rails action will get called through ajax from a route(preferably) in ember.

If you must preserve standard urls, then you must define a rails controller method for each url defined in your ember router.  Of course you could just point all urls to a 'home#index' action that responds with an empty html page.